# JBehave maintain data across steps Given/When/Then during a Scenario

Tags: bdd, jbehave

I have been trying JBehave for sometime and I need to figure out if there exists a way to maintain data across steps during the run of one particular scenario ? I mean is it possible to maintain  the state/data during a scenario across the Given/When/Then with out using 
any state variable under the Step Class.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can pass an object that maintains the shared state to the different steps.

The [Noughts And Crosses example](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/tree/master/examples/noughtsandcrosses) in [jbehave core](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core) demonstrates this. There's some share state between stories that is maintained in the class [WindowControl](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/noughtsandcrosses/src/test/java/com/lunivore/noughtsandcrosses/ui/WindowControl.java).

See that the class NoughtsAndCrossesStory that sets up the environment injects an instance of WindowControl to all the steps.