# Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll when running multiple JBehave Stories via Maven

Tags: java, windows, maven, jbehave

I'm working with a Maven project that has three modules:

- Database
- Module that contains a JBehave Story (Story .java, .story, and steps .java file)
- Another module that contains a JBehave Story (Story .java, .story, and steps .java file)

Both of the modules that contain a JBehave Story have the same type of .java file that runs the .story file and steps. Below is the .java file both modules have (but have different names for test purposes):

```
public class FirstStories extends ConfigurableEmbedder {
    private SqlDataSourceProvider dataSourceProvider = new SqlDataSourceProvider();
    private final CrossReference xref = new CrossReference();
    private Context context = new Context();
    private Format contextFormat = new ContextOutput(context);
    private ContextView contextView = new JFrameContextView().sized(640, 120);
    private ContextStepMonitor contextStepMonitor = new ContextStepMonitor(context, contextView, xref.getStepMonitor());

    public FirstStories() {
        System.setProperty("jbehave.test", "true");
        configuredEmbedder().embedderControls().doGenerateViewAfterStories(true).doIgnoreFailureInStories(false)
                .doIgnoreFailureInView(true).doVerboseFailures(true).useThreads(1).useStoryTimeouts("5m");
        configuredEmbedder().useEmbedderControls(new PropertyBasedEmbedderControls());
    }

    @Test
    @Override
    public void run() throws Throwable {
        Embedder embedder = configuredEmbedder();
        try {
            embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(storyPaths());
        } finally {
            embedder.generateCrossReference();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {
        Properties viewResources = new Properties();
        viewResources.put("decorateNonHtml", "true");
        viewResources.put("reports", "ftl/jbehave-reports-with-totals.ftl");

        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryReporterBuilder(
                        new StoryReporterBuilder()
                                .withDefaultFormats()//.withViewResources(viewResources)
                                .withFormats(contextFormat, CONSOLE, TXT, HTML_TEMPLATE, XML_TEMPLATE).withFailureTrace(true)
                                .withFailureTraceCompression(true).withCrossReference(xref))
                .useStepMonitor(contextStepMonitor);
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new Steps(dataSourceProvider));
    }

    private List<String> storyPaths() {
        String filter = System.getProperty("story.filter", "**/*.story");
        return new StoryFinder().findPaths(codeLocationFromClass(this.getClass()), filter, "**/failing_before*.story");
    }
}
```

The .story file is very straightfoward and only has one scenario:

```
Meta:

Narrative:
As a user
I want to perform an action
So that I can achieve a business goal

Scenario: Test scenario
Given nothing
When I do nothing
Then nothing happens
```

The steps file only contains one no-op method just to get everything working properly.

When running both JBehave tests via maven, the first story will run just fine. However, when starting up the second story, the following message appears, and the test shortly fails (I can run the second story on its own without issues, only when it runs after the first story):

```
WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll cause : Native Library C:\Windows\System32\sqljdbc_auth.dll already loaded in another classloader

java.sql.SQLException: An attempt by a client to checkout a Connection has timed out.
```

Is there something I am forgetting to do during my story's run() method to make sure everything is properly destroyed after the story is finished running, so the next story can run correctly without problems?

Comment: Assuming you haven't already resolved this, it's possible that the story file for test 1 does not end with a blank line?  I'm guessing the problem comes up at the end of story 1 but only presents itself if there's another story run afterwards.  Compare the text between the two story files, see if there is a difference.  Also, keep in mind that JBehave will process stories in alphabetical order, so if the output is identical, you might not be seeing the correct one that's failing - it might be test 2 running first - depends on what they are called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JBehave maintain data across steps Given/When/Then during a Scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389845/jbehave-maintain-data-across-steps-given-when-then-during-a-scenario)